# Why is my progress bar does not show up in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to code a loading screen for my Tkinter 'app' and trying to make an animated progress bar. I followed the tutorial and adapted the code into my own version. At first, when I click run, the codes run nicely, but as soon as I added a function to animate the progress bar, the progress bare stopped showing up altogether. The code I ended up with is as follow:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import sqlite3
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import winsound

#--------------Frames--------------------------
class VendingApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Loading)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        #Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one.
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class Loading(Frame):    
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)


    def load():
        for x in range(100):
            Loading_bar['value'] += 1
            root.update_idiletasks()
            time.sleep(1)
##            

        Loading_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                                      length = 500, mode = 'determinate')
        Loading_bar.pack(pady = 200)


        load()
        
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = VendingApp()
    #Sets the size of the window
    root.geometry("1024x768")
    #Renames the TITLE of the window
    root.title("Vending machine")
    root.geometry("1024x768")
    root.resizable(False, False) 


    root.mainloop()
```

I created a separate file to try to see if it would work with just tkinter and no class with this code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import*
import time

root = Tk()

def load():
    for x in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        Loading_bar['value'] += 1
        root.update_idletasks()
   
    None


Loading_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                            length = 500, mode = 'determinate')
Loading_bar.pack()

load()

root.mainloop()
```

And the result was that every time I launch it the program load indefinitely. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong, please? No need for correct code to be provided, just the error/s and some pointer on how to fix it is fine, Although correct code will be much much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sleep()` function will suspend execution and also updates to the GUI.

Try using the `after()` function instead. It schedules the `load()` function for later but does not affect the rest of your program:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import*
import time

root = Tk()

def load():
    current_value = Loading_bar.cget('value')
    if current_value < 100:
        root.after(10, load)
    Loading_bar.config(value=current_value+1)

Loading_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                            length = 500, mode = 'determinate')
Loading_bar.pack()

load()

root.mainloop()
```

**Adding new example**

I have added a new example which is a modification of your original code. I create the progress bar in the `__init__()` function of the `Loading()` class. After the progress bar reaches 100 the progress bar is removed but not destroyed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class VendingApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Loading)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class Loading(Frame):    
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.Loading_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                           length=500, mode='determinate')
        self.Loading_bar.pack(pady=200)
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        current_value = self.Loading_bar.cget('value')
        if current_value < 100:
            self.after(10, self.load)
        else:
            self.Loading_bar.pack_forget()  # Removing widget from frame
        self.Loading_bar.config(value=current_value+1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = VendingApp()
    root.geometry("1024x768")
    root.mainloop()
```

Does this work better?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply:) the troubleshooting lines of codes work beautifully, but when I adapt it into the app, the problem still persists and I don't understand why.

Comment: I added a new example by modifying your original code. Does this illustrate the solution better?